# how to make netbeans start up faster. netbeans is taking an insane amount of time just to open

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, development-environment, netbeans-7

I do not know if its just my computer, but netbeans is taking an insane amount of time just to open. I'm wondering is there anything i can do to mitigate this problem.

(Like maybe if i reduce the amount of tabs opened in netbeans it may speed things up or something)

Comment: What is your processor, available memory, OS? What is an "insane amount of time"?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: IDE's like Netbeans are not widely known to be zippity fast and lightweight.  You may have an underpowered box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reinstall from scratch is usually the best way to go. Your netbeans installation is probably slowed down by all the plugins, settings, files, cache, old files, and other stuff that its trying to load at startup. Backup your .netbeans profile folder, delete the old one, download a new netbeans installation (netbeans itself might of collected old files), and restore your settings.

If that doesn't speed things up, then really the only thing you can do is upgrade the computer

Answer (score 4):

You can use ["Scan on Demand"](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If your problem has seemingly got worse over time you can delete the .netbeans folder that is placed in your user home directory, this should speed things up in that case.

As a precursor to deleting the .netbeans folder i would run netbeans with a custom home directory

> netbeans.exe --userdir
>   c:\temp\myTestHome\

And see if that fixes the problem... If it does then delete your .netbeans folder, but be warned that it will behave as a new installation after that - ie no settings/plugins that you defined will be present anymore.

Answer (score 1):

delete your home.directory `.netbeans` folder.e every thing will be fine
. i'm using 7.0 netbeans and it's faster to deploy with tomcat 7.0.6